# What are the non-academic job prospects for a PhD in probability?

Tags: phd, job, interdisciplinary

So I am a Master of Science, majored in math, as of now. I am going to a reasonably good US university as an international student to get my PhD, which will likely be in probability, my main field of interest. I have heard a lot about how probability has applications in non-academic jobs and was wondering what would be my job prospects (in research and development) with such a PhD? I am not interested in purely academic research job.

I would like to add that I will be taking CS courses (lots of modelling courses especially), so I can bridge the gap between my knowledge of the purer side of math and its more applied side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main industry job for anyone involved with probabilities nowadays is called

> Data Scientist

(also called applied statistician which, in turn, is basically applied probabilities).

Comment: To this we may add, data management, information management, consulting at the top firms. If you are good with programming, that are endless possibilities in developing jobs. If you live in, or will relocate to, a major urban area the job prospects are endless (p ≤ 0.05)

Comment: @Repmat Agreed. It seems that Data Science (and all its byproducts) offer many possibilities to ppl with good probability education.

Comment: @PsySp  I haven't done a Data Science course yet, so I'm not so sure about this-but will my knowledge of Stochastic Calculus, Brownian Motion etc find applications there too? Just curious, because several friends of mine had done a Data Science course even though they never did advanced probability courses.

Comment: @SoumyoB Data Science is not a single course. There are even whole departments dedicated to data science. And no, you cannot do data science without good probabilistic knowledge/stochastic process and stochastic decision making.